# ¿Cómo puedo pasar con un click de una vista ListView a un nuevo Activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick

¿Cómo sería posible que pulsando un ítem, de mi listview, pueda pasar a otra actividad nueva?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create an ArrayList of AndroidFlavor objects
        final ArrayList<Hola> hola = new ArrayList<Hola>();
        hola.add(new Hola("hola1", R.drawable.ic_hola));
        hola.add(new Hola("hola2", R.drawable.ic_hola));
        hola.add(new Hola("hola3", R.drawable.ic_hola));

        HolaAdapter holaAdapter = new HolaAdapter(this, hola);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_hola);
        listView.setAdapter(holaAdapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando el metodo el metodo `setOnItemClickListener` que se ejecuta cuando se le da clic a un elemento de la lista:

```
        //...
        HolaAdapter holaAdapter = new HolaAdapter(this, hola);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_hola);
        listView.setAdapter(holaAdapter);

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    Hola holaSelecionado = hola.get(position);
                    startActivity(MainActivity.class, Actividad_A_Ejecutar.class);
                }
            });
        //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Les comparto el trozo de codigo que me funciono correctamente:

```
   ...// 

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                        if (position == 0) {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Start.class);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                        }
                    }
                });

//...
```

Comment: Supongo que sabes que ahí solo te lanzará la actividad Start cuando pulses el elemento en la posición 0 del listview.

Comment: Cuando pulses el primer item del listView.

Comment: Es correcto, solo será para el item posicionado en la posición número 1, más sin embargo solo es cuestión de copiar las mismas líneas y hacer pequeños cambios, como el número de la posición y el activity para abrir